# Meaning of "would" in "Japan Would Make Akihito Emperor, but She Called Him ‘Jimmy’ "

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does the "would" in this context :

> Japan Would Make Akihito Emperor, but She Called Him ‘Jimmy’

mean :

> Japan accepted to make Akihito Emperor

?

Source: The headline of [this](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/29/world/asia/emperor-akihito.html) newspaper article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Would* in this context is simply the past form of the modal *will*, it is used to indicate a future action in the past with reference to the simple past, i.e. a future-in-the-past tense. We can think of it thus: "would" is to the past past simple what "will"  is to the present simple.

Side note: "she" refers to the English teacher of Mr. Akihito when he was young.

Comment: To close the loop on Norbert's answer:  The full meaning of the sentence is along these lines:  _"A woman called the future emperor of Japan 'Jimmy.'"_ The phrasing (with the "but") is designed to highlight the contrast between the boy's status as emperor-to-be, and the informality with which his teacher addressed him.

Answer (score -1):

The use of would in this headline is the conditional.

> Japan would make Akihito emperor, (if some condition was met)...

It's not clear from this limited context what "Jimmy" is about.  It seems to be saying,

> Japan would make Akihito emperor, (if they could) but they can't because She (she=someone) called him "Jimmy".

Perhaps the rest of the article makes the connection clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've actually figured it out, the would (" would make" to be more precise) plays the role of a future event but in the past, as in "will make" but viewed from the past perspective, btw, "she" refers to the English teacher of Mr. Akihito when he was young.

Comment: @Norbert -- Your comment would make a good answer.  The previous sentence is a subjunctive.  It means, "If you convert your comment into an answer, then the answer will be good."